# Is there a way to Install Tensorflow2-GPU in Google Colab for good?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Is there a way I can Install Tensorflow 2- GPU in Google Colab without Installing it every time new after the Runtime ran out?

Right now I have:

```
    !pip install -U tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
```

in my Setup, so it always Installs Tf 2. But it's kind of annoying to Install it every day, so is there a way I can install it for good?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the version with e.g: `"%tensorflow_version 2.x"`, as described here: 
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb